# VB.net Regex Get Information

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex, client, irc

Well I am currently trying to get the word/text in between these 2 things

: and !

I tried this

```
        Dim nick As String = String.Empty
        Dim p = ":(?<ircnick>.*?)!"
        Dim Matches = Regex.Matches(mail, p, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
        If Matches IsNot Nothing AndAlso Matches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Match As Match In Matches
                If Match.Groups("info").Success Then
                    nick = (Match.Groups("ircnick").Value)
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

It doesn't display anything. If you guys can fix this code for me I would be happy :D.

Comment: Still looking for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx), both `:` and `!` are reserved words. Did you try escaping them?.

Comment: With what I posted it gives me this error

parsing "\:\\(?<info>?)\!\" - To many )'s